# How Can I Change the Smoothness(Curvature) of the line in line chart using Charts_flutter library?

Tags: flutter, charts

I want to display a line chart in curved form using the charts_flutter library if someone could please help which property should i use for  the same

Comment: Did you try the `fl_chart`?

Comment: yes sir i already mentioned the problem faced due to fl_charts in the comments below

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](https://github.com/google/charts/pull/166) PR, the changes are there which adds additional parameter `smoothLine: true,` to change the graph as per your requirement but it's not maintained and published on `pub.dev` yet, so you can't use it. What you can do is, clone the repo with PR and use this feature.
I would suggest you use [fl_chart](https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart), it's well-maintained library for graphs and has the feature which you want.

Comment: thank you so much for answering sir but as per your suggestion I have already tried using fl_chart but the problem faced is that I want a time-series dynamic chart, so in fl_chart I am unable to set the viewport for the same as well as I can't pass the desired FlSpot list value required in the double format because i particularly need the x-axis to be time axis

Comment: You can pass the list of all coordinates and dynamically create `LineChartBarData` by dynamically creating the `spots` parameter based on your coordinates list.